# Like query with two values

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm not really good at this stuff. I'm looking for a like query that will look for 2 column names.

Psudo query:

```
select * from tblStepCalendar 
where groupNr + groupName like " & txtGroupNum.Value txtGroupName.Value & "*';"
```

Heres one of my queries that works in my code:

```
db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblStepCalendar Where groupNr like '*" & txtGroupNum.Value & "*';", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblStepCalendar " & _
                 "Where (groupNr like '*" & txtGroupNum.Value & "*') " & _
                 " AND (groupName like '*" & txtGroupName.Value & "*')" & _
                 ";", dbOpenDynaset)
```